# Data synchronization of 2 machines over network

Tags: java, xml, soap, network-programming, synchronization

I have 2 machines set up as follows:

1. Machine 1: on a car with 3G internet.
2. Machine 2: back office machine with static IP address.

Machine 1 will run an application, which keeps generating xml data files like 1.xml, 2.xml, 3.xml, etc..., which will be stored on local folders.

I need a way to send those xml files over the internet from machine 1 to machine 2, and I need to guarantee the following conditions:

1. All xml files must be sent over to machine 2 one-by-one, i.e. if for some reasons the network is down or something like that, the interface must ensure it will re-send all failed data files. That means, eventually data on machine 1 and machine 2 must be the same.
2. Sent data must not be resent.
3. Machine 2 must send acknowledgements back to machine 1 to confirm data files received. If an acknowledgement of a data file is lost, and machine 1 re-send that data file, it should be ignored.
4. Minimize overhead over the network.

I'm thinking of using soap interface as the approach, but not sure how to implement it properly. Can someone suggest a good solution for this?

ps: interfaces must be written in Java.

thanks all.

Comment: ok, ignore the interface being used, i'm more interested in how to sync the data between the 2 machines. can you suggest a good solution or point me to an example? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP socket commmnication is good approach for this kind of requirement.

Comment: can you point me to a link or some examples. thanks.

Comment: for reference use http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

Comment: thanks rajj, that's a great start for tcp/ip programming. What's about the data synchronization protocol? I'm more interested in the logic how to sync the data between the 2 machines in case the network is down on either side. Again thanks for your help.